# Get Exception message from mule

Tags: mule, mule-el

I am upgrading from Mule 3.4 to 3.7. I have applications that handle exceptions by alerting administrators by email. In 3.4, I used to have the mule expression #[exception.getSummaryMessage()] for printing and emailing the information. It used to provide me the complete exception message with the exception stack as below:

---

Message               : groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: z for class: Script1 (javax.script.ScriptException)
Type                  : org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html
Transformer           : ScriptTransformer{this=11810917, name='ScriptTransformer', ignoreBadInput=false, returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.Object, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, sourceTypes=[]}

---

Exception stack is:
1. No such property: z for class: Script1 (groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException)
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter:53 (null)
2. groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: z for class: Script1 (javax.script.ScriptException)
  org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl:326 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/script/ScriptException.html)
3. groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: z for class: Script1 (javax.script.ScriptException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.module.scripting.transformer.ScriptTransformer:56 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)

---

In 3.7, the same expression only gives me the exception message as below:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: z for class: Script1 (javax.script.ScriptException). Message payload is of type: NullPayload (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException). Message payload is of type: NullPayload

Could someone guide me as to how I can retrieve the exception in the previous format or how this can be achieved with Mule 3.7?

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar so I wrote a piece of Groovy code to extract the error message from the exception object:

```java
def log = LogFactory.getLog(logCategory)
def cleanRootErrorMessage = null

// no matter what, we don't want Exceptions getting out of here!
try {
        log.debug("Extracting exception root cause...")
        def tmpException = exception

        while (tmpException.cause != null && (tmpException.cause instanceof NullPointerException) == false) {
                tmpException = tmpException.cause
        }

        cleanRootErrorMessage = tmpException.message
        log.debug("Root cause: [$cleanRootErrorMessage]")

        if (cleanRootErrorMessage ==~/^.*(Exception: |Error: )(.*)$/) {
                cleanRootErrorMessage = (cleanRootErrorMessage =~/^.*(Exception: |Error: )(.*)$/).replaceAll('$2')
        }

        if(cleanRootErrorMessage == null) {
                log.debug("Capturing exception.message...")
                cleanRootErrorMessage = exception.message
        }

        log.debug("Filtered root cause: [$cleanRootErrorMessage]")
} catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception thrown ***inside*** the Root Error Message extraction code...", e)
        cleanRootErrorMessage = 'Unknown Error'
}

return cleanRootErrorMessage
```

I hope it helps, if you want further help, feel free to find me on my twitter account from my profile.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try #[exception.cause.message]

Comment: I tried this.. Gives me the same response. Could you guide me to the program which mule uses to print the exception. May be I can mimic that.